# Replace all matches within the tag

Tags: php, regex

There is the following line:

```
$str = '<div class="hello"> Hello world &lt hello world?! </div>';
```

Need to find all the matches within the tag, while avoiding a match attribute values. Try something like:

```
$pattern = '/(.*)(hello)(.*)(?=<\/)/ui'; 
$replacement = '$1<span style="background:yellow">$2</span>$3';
```

but yet there is only one "hello". What to do?

Comment: Your html is unbalanced: `< hello ` is not closed

Comment: well, changed to &lt for example, then what to do?

Comment: So in your sample you would expect to find the two hellos inside the div, but not the .hello class?  You might be better off using DomDocument (http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: @HookeD74 what would be your expected output?

Answer (score 2):

**(*SKIP)(*F) Syntax in Perl and PCRE (PHP, Delphi, R...)**

With all the disclaimers about using regex to parse html, we can do this with a surprisingly simple regex:

```
<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|(hello)
```

**Sample PHP Code:**

```
$replaced = preg_replace('~<[^>]*>(*SKIP)(*F)|(hello)~i',
                        '<span style="background:yellow">$1</span>',
                         $yourstring);
```

In the [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/32), see the substitutions at the bottom.

**Explanation**

This problem is a classic case of the technique explained in this question to ["regex-match a pattern, excluding..."](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)

The left side of the alternation  `|` matches complete `<tags>` then deliberately fails, after which the engine skips to the next position in the string. The right side captures `hello` (case-insensitive to Group 1, and we know they are the right ones because they were not matched by the expression on the left.

**Reference**

- [How to match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174/)
- [Article about matching a pattern unless...](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html)

Comment: FYI: Added demo and explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

Wrapping text matches into another element is a pretty basic operation, though the code is somewhat tricky:

```
$html = <<<EOS
<div class="hello"> Hello world &lt; hello world?! </div>
EOS;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);

$search = 'hello';

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('div') as $element) {
    foreach ($element->childNodes as $node) { // iterate all direct descendants
        if ($node->nodeType == 3) { // and look for text nodes in particular
            if (($pos = strpos($node->nodeValue, $search)) !== false) {
                // we split the text up in: <prefix> match <postfix>
                $postfix = substr($node->nodeValue, $pos + strlen($search));
                $node->nodeValue = substr($node->nodeValue, 0, $pos);

                // insert <postfix> behind the current text node
                $textNode = $dom->createTextNode($postfix);
                if ($node->nextSibling) {
                    $node->parentNode->insertBefore($textNode, $node->nextSibling);
                } else {
                    $node->parentNode->appendChild($textNode);
                }

                // wrap match in an element and insert it    
                $wrapNode = $dom->createElement('span', $search);
                $element = $node->parentNode->insertBefore($wrapNode, $textNode);
            }
        }
    }
}

echo $dom->saveHTML(), "\n";
```